# How to place JTextArea object at a certain place on a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, jtextarea

I am trying to implement a JAVA GUI app, but I am facing a problem that I could not find the solution anywhere about how to move the JTextArea to a certain place on the panel. I took a picture of the software.

I have tried many ways to make the white JTextArea object placed below the big JTextArea object on the right panel. Does anyone have any idea about this? Like how to move the JTextArea object around the others, and how to make the JButton/JTextArea objects stay in the fixed place?

```
public class menu extends JFrame {
    private JButton generate, sort;
    private final JTextArea TEXT_AREA_EAST = new JTextArea(30,40);
    private final JTextArea TEXT_AREA_WEST = new JTextArea(30,40);
    private final JTextArea TEXT_AREA_EAST_BELOW = new JTextArea(5,30);

    private void display() {
        setTitle ("Sorting Algorithm Runtime Calculator");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500,300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2,5,5));

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.white);
        contentPane.setBorder(
        BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(horizontal, horizontal, horizontal, horizontal));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(horizontal, vertical)); 
        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();

        rightPanel = new JPanel();
        rightPanel.setOpaque(true);
        rightPanel.setBackground(Color.yellow);        
        border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Sorted List");
        border.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.CENTER);
        rightPanel.setBorder(border);        
        sort = new JButton("Sort");    

        rightPanel.add(sort, JPanel.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
        rightPanel.add(TEXT_AREA_EAST, BorderLayout.EAST);
        rightPanel.add(TEXT_AREA_EAST_BELOW, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        TEXT_AREA_EAST.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        TEXT_AREA_EAST.setEditable(false);
```

[This is how the app look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bd3l.png)

Comment: Have a look at the guide on layout managers - it should help.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html.

Comment: Is there any way to use BordeLayout? I did try BoxLayout, but I need to show the text, and keep the text updated frequently.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.